# not seeing a meta link on main page

Tags: bug

[image: screen shot now]

The Physics Meta panel on the right is a chat, not active since the June 24 bug? 
Or does it only appear when an interesting/popular  subject is being discussed?

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking about the "Featured meta posts" section that would ordinarily appear in the yellow box:

[image: closeup of right sidebar with freehand circle showing no meta posts]

That isn't showing up because there are no meta posts eligible to show right now. It's not a bug, it's just an unusual situation which is why it might look weird.

Meta questions become eligible to appear in the box in two ways:

- A moderator manually applies the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag to the question.
- The question is recent, active, and has a reasonably positive score. The specific criteria are [listed on mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/56541).

Incidentally, the thing you see that is labeled "Physics Meta" is simply a link to a chat room, and it only has that label because the chat room is called "Physics Meta". It has (almost) no relationship to this meta site that we are currently reading. We should probably come up with a different name for that room at some point.

The chat room links are completely separate from the links to meta posts that would normally appear in the yellow box. I believe there are always two chat rooms shown, and they are chosen from among all chat rooms associated with this site using some criteria related to recent activity - though I'm not sure what exactly those criteria are.

Comment: OK, thanks. That is how I link to Meta. Maybe there should be a link to the physics meta at some place on the first page. I did not remember the link, whether meta comes before physics or after. I tried the before ( physics comes before .stackexchange was my logic) .

Comment: Click on "Stack Exchange" at the top left

Comment: Thanks, had not seen it .